# optimal values of a,b,c,d,e based on data passed to a function with known ground truth values

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, gradient, gradient-descent

I have a function which takes several parameters - a,b,c,d,e and the returns the computed value of z.

I also have the ground truth value of z and I would like to compute the optimal parameters of a,b,c,d,e which would minimize the error between the ground truth value z and the approximated value of z by the function.

I have lots of data for the computed value of z and the ground truth z given different input values of a,b,c,d,e.

Any suggestion how to find the optimal parameters of a,b,c,d and e? I was thinking something like gradient descent or optimization but I am not sure how to proceed.

z1 = function (a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + e1)  and  error1 = z1 - z1' where z'1 is the ground truth

z2 = function (a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 + e2)  and  error2 = z2 - z2' where z2' is the ground truth

... ... .... ... .... ... ... .... ... .... ... .... ..... .... .... .......................................................................

zn = function (an + bn + cn + dn + en)  and  errorn = zn - zn' where zn' is the ground truth

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Ash

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is to estimate the value of **y**, with the values of **x1**,**x2**,**x3**,**x4** and **x5** given.

You can use something simple as *[Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)* for predicting the value of **y** with other parameters given.

Now, as you probably guessed, the equation to solve for y will be something like this:

`y = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + ...` where your goal will be to predict a set of coefficients which are able to predict your **y** correctly, given **x1..x5**. Such optimization can be done by *[Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)*

Here are some of the simple python code to achieve such result:

```
# Make a prediction with coefficients
def predict(row, coefficients):
    yhat = coefficients[0]
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        yhat += coefficients[i + 1] * row[i]
        return yhat

# Estimate linear regression coefficients using stochastic gradient descent
def coefficients_sgd(train, l_rate, n_epoch):
    coef = [0.0 for i in range(len(train[0]))]
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        sum_error = 0
        for row in train:
            yhat = predict(row, coef)
            error = yhat - row[-1]
            sum_error += error**2
            coef[0] = coef[0] - l_rate * error
            for i in range(len(row)-1):
                coef[i + 1] = coef[i + 1] - l_rate * error * row[i]
        print('>epoch=%d, lrate=%.3f, error=%.3f' % (epoch, l_rate, sum_error))
    return coef
```

For testing, let's feed very simple data into the function and see the results.

```
# Calculate coefficients
dataset = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 3], [3, 2], [5, 5]]
l_rate = 0.001
n_epoch = 50
coef = coefficients_sgd(dataset, l_rate, n_epoch)
print(coef)
```

This is the output:

> epoch=45, lrate=0.001, error=2.650
>
> epoch=46, lrate=0.001, error=2.627
>
> epoch=47, lrate=0.001, error=2.607
>
> epoch=48, lrate=0.001, error=2.589
>
> epoch=49, lrate=0.001, error=2.573
>
> [0.22998234937311363, 0.8017220304137576]

Comment: I am looking for the optimal values of  x1,x2,x3,x4 and x5 this data - not the coefficients - I have edited the title to make things clearer

Comment: What if x1..x5 are all random? how can you find optimal x1..x5 to predict z? I am sure you have messed up some assumptions.

Comment: I am supplying the x1 to x5 to the function to get z- they are not random.